# Howto recursively update groups in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using sql Server 2008.

following dataPool:

```
PK  Col1        Col2
1   SomeValue1  DataToTake1
2   SomeValue1
3   SomeValue1
4   SomeValue1
5   SomeValue2  DataToTake2
6   SomeValue2
...
```

i want to insert `DataToTake1` into `Col2` of records with `PK` 2, 3 and 4 and `DataToTake2` into `Col2` of record with `PK` 6.
to make it more obvious: records with `PK` 1-4 are groups, indicated by `Col1`
another info: `PK` might not be incremental nor sequenced on productive system (but as we can group by `Col1`, i hope that might not be a problem).

is there any way to to this with sql Server? (a companion implemented this with a pointer ... arggggh)

**edit**
thank you for your answers, but i have to revise my request, as my initial situation changed: i need to take PK in account. eg.

```
PK  Col1        Col2
1   SomeValue1  DataToTake1
2   SomeValue1
4   SomeValue1
5   SomeValue2  DataToTake2
6   SomeValue2
9   SomeValue1
```

how to only update sequenced rows? with this example, PK 1 = 2 = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to use temporary tables:

create table #DataToTake (
  seq int not null identity(1, 1),
  PK_S int not null, -- set this to same type as PK in dataPool
  PK_E int null, -- set this to same type as PK in dataPool
  Col1 varchar(20) null, -- set this to same type as Col1 in dataPool
  Col2 varchar(20) null -- set this to same type as Col2 in dataPool
)

insert into #DataToTake 
(PK_S, Col1, Col2)
select PK, Col1, Col2
from dataPool
where Col2 is not null
order by PK

update #DataToTake set
  PK_E = dtt2.PK_S
from #DataToTake inner join #DataToTake dtt2 on
  #DataToTake.seq = dtt2.seq - 1

update #DataToTake set
  PK_E = (select Max(PK) + 1 from dataPool)
where PK_S = (select Max(PK_S) from #DataToTake )

update dataPool set
  Col2 = dtt.Col2
from dataPool inner join #DataToTake dtt on
  dataPool.PK > dtt.PK_S
  and dataPool.PK < dtt.PK_E
  and dataPool.Col1 = dtt.Col1

drop table #DataToTake

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE
   D1
SET
   Col2 = D2.Col1
FROM
   dataPool D1
   JOIN
   dataPool D2 ON D1.col1 = D2.col1
WHERE
   D1.col2 <> D2.col2 OR D1.col2 IS NULL
```

Comment: thank you for solution, but my request has changed. could you maybe help?

Comment: This changes the code drastically. I'll see if I have time later: sorry I can't do anything now

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Select the top 1 value which has data, and matches whats in Col1
UPDATE dataPool
SET Col2 = (SELECT TOP 1 t3.Col2 
            FROM dataPool t3 
            WHERE t3.col1 = t2.col1 
            AND t3.Col2 IS NOT NULL) -- 
FROM dataPool t2
WHERE t2.Col1 = Col1
AND col2 IS NULL -- Only update Rows with NULLs in
```

Comment: thank you for solution, but my request has changed. could you maybe help?